# Normalization understanding

Tags: normalization, database-normalization

Hi i have been currently trying to learn some database's fundamentals and my problem is understanding normalization.

What would 2nf and 3nf be on something like this

CustNo(pk), CustBal, CustDiscount

OrdNo(pk),  CustNo, ShipAddr, OrderDate

ItemNo(pk)  ItemDesc

ItemNo(pk), PlantNo(pk), ReorderPoint, QtyOnHand

OrderNo(pk), ItemNo(pk), LineNo, QtyOrdered, QtyOutstanding

OrderNo(pk), LineNo(pk),  ItemNo, QtyOrdered, QtyOutstanding

Comment: To really understand database normalization, you have first to understand functional dependencies, see for instance the definition of [3nf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). What are the functional dependencies of your examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization is not an end in itself. Normalization is a design activity informed by the requirements of what you are designing. You are modeling something that exists in the real world -- manufacturing orders, in this case -- and you want to engineer the representation.

For example, consider these two relations you have defined:

- ItemNo(pk) ItemDesc
- ItemNo(pk), PlantNo(pk), ReorderPoint, QtyOnHand

Is ReorderPoint set for each item on a per-plant basis, or are there policies that inventory planners set for items that cause a ReorderPoint to be calculated? It is possible to have:

- ReorderPoint hang off (ItemNo, PlantNo) as you have done;
- ReorderPoint hang off ItemNo (at the Item Master level);
- Some other attributes of the item that define reorder policies (EOQ, dependent item, etc.) and have no permanent ReorderPoint at all.

The requirements define what you want to model, and from there it is possible to normalize. It is also possible to overnormalize, which has a negative effect on performance.